# How to get included values of jsonapi on a router with ember-data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

I'm using jsonapi directives to make a connection between ember.js app and an API. I have a `track` that could have like 50 or more `comments` and I need to load them on a route to perform some logic.

This is and example response of the API:

```
{
   "data": {
       "id": 1,
       "type": "track",
       "attributes": {
           "name": "XPTO"
       },
       "relationships": {
           "comment": {
               "data": [
                   {"id": 1, "type": "comment"}
               ]
           }
       }
   },
   "include": [
       {
          "id": 1,
          "type": "comment",
          "attributes": {
             "text": "Lorem ipsum..."
          }
       }
   ]
}
```

Now imagine it with 50 comments, this would be very consuming to make a request for each call. If I do it in a view with an `each` loop, it doesn't make all the requests, but it I try to access it in a Route, it will make all the requests. How do I achieve that with the following code?

```
this.store.findRecord('track', 1).then((t) => {
   // logic here
   // I tried this but it would make all the requests too
   t.get('comments');
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use property "coalesceFindRequests" in your adapter

```
coalesceFindRequests: true
```

If you set coalesceFindRequests to true it will instead trigger the following request:

```
GET /comments?ids[]=1&ids[]=2
```

so this makes only one call for all the comments.

> Note: Requests coalescing rely on URL building strategy. So if you
>   override buildURL in your app groupRecordsForFindMany more likely
>   should be overridden as well in order for coalescing to work.